# HTTP SOAP payload Encoding

Tags: java, http, soap, soapui

```
POST http://xxx/test HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: xxx:1041
Content-Length: 1911

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prop="http://...">
   <soapenv:Header>
    .....
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      .....
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When i look via SOAP UI i see that Accept-Encoding is gzip,deflate.
This means the SOAP payload is zipped before is sent via http ? and on server side unzipped as part of the HTTP protocol ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Accept-Encoding` is a request header and in your particular case means, that party is just able to accept zipped content. In turn, response header `Content-Encoding` shows whether message was really gzipped.

Answer (score 1):

`Accept-Encoding` is an http header that defines encoding that the client will accept as a response. It does not mean that the request was encoded using either of those values just that the server may respond with them.

For further detail see [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1 (RFC 2616 Section 14.3)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3)

Answer (score -1):

Accept-Encoding indicates the client sending the request can accept encoded responses defined as the value of this parameter.

To Gzip requests you'll have to set the `Content-Encoding: gzip parameter`. You may do this using a SOAP client like SOAPUI for testing.

To send a Gzipped request using SOAP UI.

Click on `File --> Preferences`.

HTTP Settings tab will be selected by default. You will notice Chunking Threshold option. By default, this is set to empty so that the chunking is disabled for any HTTP request.

Update this field with non negative integer value (e.g:- 1) and resubmit your request. You will notice encoded request as shown below.

```
POST http://<.....>n HTTP/1.1
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 206
Host: amazona-bs4anhc:4400
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```